# Long trips to the server on non-rapid demand

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I have business  asp.net application. Application sits on different server than sql-server; but both are on the same farm. On the website there is grid, and after selecting its row some ajax actions are taken on server including running simple query to sql.

Now the problem is, when I click on row by row in time < 2sec, then respond from server is taking about 2sec. But when i am idle for more than 2 sec, respond from server takes 4-6 sec and sometimes (about 30%) i can see 401 anuathorized message taking about 1sec - all those results are obtained by firebug.

My question is: why is there such difference in times and how can I fix it or investigate it further ,so all calls would take about 2sec.

Comment: there isn't nearly enough information here to provide an answer. I can say that you will need to profile the application to determine where the bottleneck is. tools like `JetBrain's dotTrace` and `Ant's .Net Profiler` will help you pinpoint where the bottlenecks are in the code. I'm sure there are other tools for profiling IIS and webfarms which would also provide the details required to resolve this issue.